# Firebase numChildren() always returns 0 in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to get the child count from the firebase database. And each time whenever I execute my code I'm getting 0 as an output instead of an actual count or is there any alternative method to get the count of the number of children from the database.

```
this.itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('sample').child((new Date(), 'dd-mmm-yyyy').toLowercase()).child('dataContainer')

this.itemsRef.on('value', snapShot => {
     this.state.count = snapShot.numChildren()
})
```

JSON data:

```
  "sample" : {
  "20-jun-2018" : {
    "dataContainer" : {
      "1" : {
        "header" : "sample",
        "price" : 2.33
      },
      "-LFTL4hUnVr4WbZRMeBU" : {
        "header" : "item",
        "imageLink" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/annam-6e679.appspot.com/o/Specials%2Fshawaramas?alt=media&token=a7907c48-005d-4d52-bb6e-26e97bda0c4e",
        "price" : "5.65"
      }
    }
  },
  "21-jun-2018" : {
    "dataContainer" : [ null, {
      "header" : "widget",
      "imageLink" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/annam-6e679.appspot.com/o/Specials%2FMasala%20Dosai?alt=media&token=a103c1be-37a1-4ca3-9da8-5f87d5c870a8",
      "price" : "8.68"
    }, {
      "header" : "images"
    } ]
  },
  "22-jun-2018" : {
    "dataContainer" : [ null, {
      "header" : "sample data",
      "imageLink" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/annam-6e679.appspot.com/o/Specials%2FDosai?alt=media&token=1191f1bb-6035-46b0-b24c-7b18bef65036",
      "price" : "4.56"
    }, {
      "header" : "data"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON at `/sample/dataContainer` (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also check the logging output of your code for relevant messages about not having access to the data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   I'm just trying to get the count of the children under the sample/date/dataContainer but whenever I'm calling the numChildren() It retrieves zero. Even after entering data of several children under dataContainer. Is there any other way to retrieve the child count from the database.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsbin.com/macaviw/edit?js,console

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's working fine. The problem was in 
child((new Date(), 'dd-mmm-yyyy').toLowerCase()). Thats the reason its not working.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you and loved your videos from Firebase YouTube channel :)